# Splice a list of vectors into a vector without unquote splice

Tags: vector, clojure

Is there a way I can do the following without `unquote-splice`? `map` returns a list of vectors.

```
(def base-html
  `[:html
    [:head ~@(map include-css ["css/reset.css"
                               "css/main.css"])]
    [:body]])

=> [:html 
     [:head 
       [:link {:href "css/reset.css", :rel "stylesheet"}] 
       [:link {:href "css/main.css", :rel "stylesheet"}]] 
     [:body]]
```

Comment: If you are using [Hiccup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) to generate html, then it will automatically expand sequences into the element for you.

Comment: @A.Webb I'm using `enlive` and ended up writing a macro plus relying on the behavior you mention. I don't know how reliable that behavior is but it seems to be working. If things start breaking I'll look into this again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suffice?

```
(def base-html
  [:html
    (vec (cons :head (map include-css ["css/reset.css"
                                       "css/main.css"])))
    [:body]])
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is much better than the original solution. What if you wanted to have `[:script]` following `[:link]`?

Comment: I'd use concat, e.g. (concat [:head] (map ...) [[:script]])